# how to detect image file in android

Tags: android, android-gallery

I have a requirement where existing image file extension being changed to something else and saved on device.

When i change extension of .jpg to some thing like .xyz, this same image file is not being detected by android as a image file and not able to open the same. Even gallery doesnot detect this file.

Now how to make android detect this file as a image file ?

-Thanks & regards,
Manju

Comment: you can use pattern matching. `file.getAbosutePath().endWith(".jpg|.xyz)`

Comment: Please add some code so we can see what have you used.

Comment: I renamed a valid .jpg file to .xyz and copied back to device and trying to view the same in gallery which is not able to detect the file type. I tried Bitmap.decode but it returns null

Answer (score 2):

Convert file path to URI:

```
    File file = new File(path + File.pathSeparator + filename);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

Then , use Content Resolver to get the file MIME type:

```
    String mimeType = getContentResolver().getType(uri);
```

That is the standard recommended method.

Hope that helps..

Comment: tried above example but it returns null, I renamed a valid .jpg file to .xyz and copied back to device and trying to decode the same returns null

Comment: @Manju Didn't understand you. Can you explain?

Comment: Hi Sanjeev, pasted sample code above for your referece.  I have copied a .jpg file created from camera to another file by extension .icy and trying to open the same in gallery or trying to get bitmap info for the same said file by code where it is returning me null.

Answer (score 0):

You can check by decoding to a bitmap , only image files can be decoded to bitmap.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
if(null!=bmp)
{
//image file
} else {
not image file.
}
```

## My Code below

```
String fileName="/storage/emulated/0/JP2/20131219_120037_16.icy";
   File file = new File(fileName);

   if(file!=null && file.exists()){
    Log.d("Manju ==>","image file: "+fileName+", does exist");
   }else{
    Log.e("Manju ==>","image file: "+fileName+", doesnot exist !!");
   }

    Uri uri=Uri.fromFile(file);
    String mimeType = getContentResolver().getType(uri);
    Log.d("Manju ==>","mime Type: "+mimeType);

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName);
    if(null!=bmp){
       //image file
    Log.d("Manju ==>","image file valid, height: "+bmp.getHeight()+", width: "+bmp.getWidth());
    } else {
    Log.d("Manju ==>","image file invalid !!!");
    }
```

Comment: i tried above example and it fails !! bmp is NULL, but the image file is valid. I renamed a valid .jpg file to .xyz and copied back to device and trying to decode the same returns null

Comment: have you double checked the file path.If it is wrong then also the bmp will be null.

Comment: is this log "Log.d("Manju ==>","image file: "+fileName+", does exist");" showing? if it is showing, you can try Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: 12-20 11:28:53.761: D/Manju ==>(9171): image file: /storage/emulated/0/JP2/20131219_120037_16.icy, does exist
12-20 11:28:53.761: D/Manju ==>(9171): mime Type: null
12-20 11:28:53.766: D/Manju ==>(9171): image file invalid !!!
12-20 11:28:53.766: D/Manju ==>(9171): After BitmapFactory.decodeFile, height: -1, width: -1, type: null

Comment: @ nikvs, I have updated my comments with output of this sample code, do you have any suggestions for the same.

Comment: Try using "Environment.getExternalStorageDicrectory()" instead of "/storage/emulated"

Comment: @ nikvs, from logs, 12-20 11:28:53.761: D/Manju ==>(9171): image file: /storage/emulated/0/JP2/20131219_120037_16.icy, does exist

Comment: which means the file exists, is it still need to use "Environment.getExternalStorageDicrectory()" instead of "/storage/emulated"

Comment: instead of using "BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName);" try "BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());"